# SSRS report inside classic asp web application

Tags: url, reporting-services, asp-classic, ssrs-2012

I've got a classic asp web application which I am trying to bring some SSRS reporting services into. I have created a classic page within the web app that links to a sql table to have the links for all our ssrs reports. This works correctly and I can view the report within a frame of the asp app with all the menu's of the classic asp around the side and bottom.

However I want to use urls within the ssrs report to go to various parts of the asp app such as open an order to view that orders details. But when i open these links from SSRS it opens by itself not within the frame so we no longer have the buttons to navigate to other parts of the asp site and the back button takes us back to the main page rather than back to the report.

I have researched this and tried different urls extensions such as

[http://classicsite/orders/jobnumber=1111&rc%3ALinkTarget=_blank]

and javascript versions which I cannot get to do anything when opened in the classic site

Please help on how I can achieve this, I don't have much programming or SSRS experience so but I am experienced with SQL and other reporting systems so a solution from SSRS would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this I was previously concentrating on where the SSRS calls the hyplerink but this needed to be fixed where the asp page calls the ssrs report with the addition of at the end of the link to the report.

&rc:linkTarget=_self